# What is one command to specify a file and what text is in it in that order without repetition?

Tags: linux, files, terminal, text

I'm looking for the perfect way to make a file.
I want to specify the file name first
I want to specify the text content for that file.
I want to do it in one console line.
I don't want to have to retype the file name.
Ideal

Answer (score 1):

Just put the redirection before the command:

```
>filename.txt printf '%s\n' "This is the first line" "This is the second line" 'This line has "double-quotes"' '' 'That fourth line is empty' '"I don'\''t think I can avoid using both types of quotes," she said.'
```

Actually, you can put the redirection anywhere in the command, so the following might seem "more natural" (although the effect is exactly identical):

```
printf '%s\n' >filename.txt "This is the first line" "This is the second line" 'This line has "double-quotes"' '' 'That fourth line is empty' '"I don'\''t think I can avoid using both types of quotes," she said.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own function, e.g.
`function createFile() { echo "$2" > $1; }`
Then call it:
`createFile myFile.txt "here the text content"`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cat >filename <<'END'
contents contents
contents contents
END
```

This invokes the `cat` command, redirects its output to the file that you want to create (or overwrite), and redirects the contents of the file from a quoted multi-line here-document delimited by the word `END`.

For a single line of text, you could use a here-string in `bash`:

```bash
cat >filename <<<"this is the contents"
```

For just pasting text into a file from a the clipboard, use `cat >filename` at the command line, then paste the data into the terminal and finish with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.